# TF serving "Could not find variable sequential_2/dense_6/kernel. This could mean that the variable has been deleted

Tags: python, tensorflow

I generated a model using TensorFlow, and both reading the model and making predictions with it work well. However, when I use TensorFlow Serving and make requests, it doesn't work. The official demo model still works."
It seems like you've created a model using TensorFlow and it works well for reading and making predictions. However, when you use TensorFlow Serving and make requests, it doesn't work as expected. The official demo model, on the other hand, still works.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "2"

def main():
num_epochs = 1
batch_size = 32
learning_rate = 0.001

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(120, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100),
    tf.keras.layers.Softmax()
])

(train, train_label), (test, test_label) = \
    tf.keras.datasets.cifar100.load_data()

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.sparse_categorical_accuracy]
)
model.fit(train, train_label, epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=batch_size)
print("tf.saved_model.save")
tf.saved_model.save(model, "/mnt/d/pythonaijia/model/mnist/300")
{
    "error": "Could not find variable sequential_2/dense_6/kernel. This could mean that the variable has been deleted. In TF1, it can also mean the variable is uninitialized. Debug info: container=localhost, status error message=Resource localhost/sequential_2/dense_6/kernel/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.\n\t [[{{function_node __inference_serving_default_84197}}{{node sequential_2_1/dense_6_1/Cast/ReadVariableOp}}]]"
}
```

I have tried many times to generate my own model, but it is not easy to use the official demo model